# How do I find the immutable id of my Google Apps account?

Tags: google-admin-sdk

Many of the Directory API calls require a **customer** parameter referred to as the "Immutable id of the Google Apps account. (string)".

e.g. GET https://www.googleapis.com/admin/directory/v1/customer/***customer***/domains

I have no idea how to find/generate this for my Google Apps account. I am an admin.

Can someone point me in the right direction please?

Comment: You can call the method Users.get with your own account, at the end of the response you can find the customerId.

Answer (score 16):

I was able to find the customerId as follows

1. Go to admin.google.com
2. Security -> Set up single sign-on (SSO)

You will see URLs like this:

https://accounts.google.com/o/saml2/idp?idpid=Cxxxxxxxx

That Cxxxxxxxx is your customerId

Comment: Couldn't find it this way; perhaps they changed the link structure?

Comment: I am able to still see the same URLs and cust id, Just tried this now.

Answer (score 6):

Had the same question, so I had to contact their chat support.

The official answer was:
There are no any web interface to look up this information - as I would expect for example in "organisation admin panel". The only way to get this information is from the code.

You have to write extra code to request information about any existing user:
([Link to API Docs](https://developers.google.com/resources/api-libraries/documentation/admin/directory_v1/python/latest/admin_directory_v1.users.html#get) - GET: https://www.googleapis.com/admin/directory/v1/users)
And in the response, you can find field `customerId` which is the same for each user in the company across all domains.

That is the only way to find your organisation `customerId`...

Not user-friendly, so I will submit "Feature Request" right now to Google.

Comment: This method required the customer id which left me puzzled. I later found that 'my_customer' can be used in place of the customer id and indeed the actual customer id is included in the response.

Answer (score 3):

The easiest way I found was to use the [APIs Explorer at the bottom of the documentation](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/reference/customers/get#try-it) for the *Customers: get* method on the Directory API (Admin SDK). Enter 'my_customer' for the customerKey on the form and hit the 'Authorize and Execute' button.

The response will include the CustomerId (e.g. Cxxxxxxxx) as the "id". The [entire response](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/reference/customers) will look something like this:

```
{
  "kind": "admin#directory#customer",
  "id": string,
  "etag": etag,
  "customerDomain": string,
  "alternateEmail": string,
  "postalAddress": {
    "organizationName": string,
    "countryCode": string,
  },
  "language": string,
  "customerCreationTime": datetime
}
```

Answer (score 3):

If you are part of an organization, you can find it here as Organization ID: https://play.google.com/work/adminsettings?pli=1

It works for G Suite accounts and Gmail accounts that are associated with an organization, but not for individual Gmail accounts.

Answer (score 0):

I found something simpler: `gcloud organizations list`. It will give you DISPLAY_NAME, ID and DIRECTORY_CUSTOMER_ID (this is what your are looking for) for all you organizations.